# What might be another expression for "to build that loss into something"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-meaning, phrase-request, idioms, idiom-request

The sentence is from a business talk about the amount financial loss, which is caused some of their products being damaged during transportation. The man from the company says:

**"Of course we build that loss into the prices we quote for our exports."**

I can understand what he meant by **"...build that loss into the prices"**. He means they increase the price of their exports to balance the loss caused by those faulty products.

But, I have been trying to find a better and easier expression for this, rather than **"build that loss into**"?

Do you any such easier and clear expression?

Regards,

Comment: "We allow for that possibility when fixing our prices" would be one way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sentence "We need to adjust/increase prices to compensate our loss".